# Can you git diff without knowing the previous commit?

Tags: git, version-control

```
git diff id_old id_newer
```

Is the standard simple use of git diff. Can you give git diff the new commit id alone and ask it to report the diff between it and the previous file changing commit without knowing it?
Something like:

```
git diff id_newer --fromlastchange  (vs --fromlastcommit)
```

Comment: Yes: `git diff newcommit~ newcommit` (the `~` means parent)

Comment: From the ridiculous documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions

Comment: I'll try that ... but parent ... is that what I want?  I wanted "a" parent, but one that was different - the nearest one.  Thanks

Comment: The parent of (previous commit to) the commit in question. You can also look at `git show <commit>`

Comment: @user116032, please be sure to read carefully the output of `git help revisions` -- as suggested by @Nayuki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to do

```
git diff id_newer^!
```

Which should give you the changes of the `id_newer` commit.